# How can I combine counting rows in an IDictionary with merging rows?

Tags: c#

I have the following class that checks for errors:

```
   public bool ValidateAccountDeletion(Account account)
    {
        var _errors = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var accounts = _accountRepository.GetPk(account.PartitionKey);
        if (_productRepository.GetPk("0000" + account.RowKey).Count() != 0)
            _errors.Add("", "Account contains products");
        return _errors;
    }
```

and the following extension class to merge my IDictionary and the ModelStateDictionary

```
public static class ModelExtensions {
    public static bool HasValue(this string value) {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && value.Trim().Length > 0;
    }

    public static void Merge(this ModelStateDictionary modelState, IDictionary<string, string> dictionary) {
        Guard.AgainstNullParameter(modelState, "modelState");
        Guard.AgainstNullParameter(dictionary, "dictionary");

        foreach(var item in dictionary) {
            modelState.AddModelError(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
```

When I call the validate and the then try to merge it doesn't look clean:

```
        var errors = _accountService.ValidateAccount(vm.Account);
        if (errors.Count > 0) 
            this.ModelState.Merge(errors)
```

Is there some way that I could maybe have a different constructor to merge and then just feed in the output
of:

```
 _accountService.ValidateAccount(vm.Account);
```

I am trying to think of how I could do this but can't think of a simple way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `Merge` method is basically doing nothing in the case of no errors you could just do

```
ModelState.Merge(_accountService.ValidateAccount(vm.Account));
```

The check for error count is unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah.  Basically, let `Merge` decide how it wants to handle the `errors.Count == 0` case itself.